# I lost my passport; can I travel with a copy of the lost visa?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens

I lost my passport. I filed a first information report (FIR). I have already gotten a new passport. The lost passport had a visa for 3 months family visit which was recently issued. The visa will expire in October. I have a copy of the visa. Original hard copy of the visa is with my husband.

I want to know if I can travel on the same visa which was in the lost passport.  Do I need to get a new visa because it will be registered with a different passport?

Comment: This run-on sentence wall of text really needs to be cleaned up to be less difficult to read.

Comment: Try again, in English, without dubious abbreviations and acronyms...

Comment: @brhans I agree.  Ramya: in addition, some words cannot be understood.  Perhaps they are abbreviations, or perhaps they are mistyped.  Can you edit the question to clarify?  I'm particularly speaking of *fir, psk,* and *ias.*  Also, the phrase "passport is empty visa copy" does not make sense.

Comment: What country issued the visa?

Comment: @ramya I assumed that your passpart is from India based on FIR and MSK usage. Please update the question if I made a mistake.

Comment: No, for obvious security reasons...

Comment: i am having family visit visa for oman recently issued and valid til oct. but i lost the passport and reissued got new passport can i travel to same visa which is mentioned old passport no

Comment: can any one help me out please
i am having family visit visa for oman recently issued and valid til oct. but i lost the passport and reissued got new passport can i travel to same visa which is mentioned old passport no.

Answer (score 3):

Having replaced your lost passport with a new passport, you will need to apply for a new visa.  A copy of a visa does not suffice.

There may be some country somewhere that is an exception to this, but since you have not said which country issued the visa, it is impossible to investigate whether it would apply in your case.  I am certain, however, that the above is correct for the US, the UK, and the Schengen area.

Comment: hi its for muscut

Comment: @Ramya "muscut" is not the name of a country in English.

Comment: i am having family visit visa for oman recently issued and valid til oct. but i lost the passport and reissued got new passport can i travel to same visa which is mentioned old passport no.